# form making with using laravel

Tags: laravel, forms

I need to display this information on a different page by getting 4 different information from the user (for example: name, surname, phone number and email) and I need to do this with laravel

```
<form method="POST" action="/register">
  @csrf

  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>

  <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname"><br><br>

  <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br><br>

  <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

I wrote a code like this but I couldn't continue

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{{route('register')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf

  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>

  <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname"><br><br>

  <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br><br>

  <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

   <input   type="submit"  name="submit">
```

so you should use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to send multi request to your route and use `{{route('register')}}`
and at the end you must defined in `web.php`

```
Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get logged-in user information in your blade files like below for example if you want to get the user name

```
{{ auth()->user()->name }}
```

or if you want to take user id

```
{{ auth()->user()->id}}
```

Comment: That's a "signup" form, user is not logged in yet